# htaccess redirect 301?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have question how to redirect this link:

```
http://rude.su.lt/~veikutis/katalogas.php?link=dulkiu-siurbliai&id=1
```

To this link:

```
http://rude.su.lt/~veikutis/dulkiu-siurbliai/1/
```

With htaccess 301 redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in `DocumentRoot`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\~veikutis)/([\w\d-]+)/([\d-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/katalogas.php?link=%2&id=%3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} flink=([\w\d-]+)&id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(~veikutis) /$1/%1/%2/? [L,R]
```